# Привязаны ли переменные окружения, создаваемые с помощью вызова putenv, к области видимости функции?

Tags: c++, linux, posix

Внутри функции создаю переменную окружения с помощью вызова putenv, но ее нельзя использовать нигде, кроме самой функции. В main ее не получается взять с помощью getenv, но внутри самой функции все прекрасно берется. Как установить переменную окружения, которая будет действовать во всей области видимости программы?

```
void test()
{
    string variable = "test=privet";
    char buf[variable.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < variable.length(); i++)
        buf[i] = variable[i];
    buf[variable.length()] = '\0';
    putenv(buf);
    //cout << getenv("test"); // значение берется внутри функции
}
int main()
{
    test();
    cout << getenv("test"); // результата нет

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я просто процитирую [`man putenv`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=putenv&russian=0&category=&submit=%F0%CF%CB%C1%DA%C1%D4%D8%20man):

> Начиная с версии 2.1.2 glibc соответствует SUSv2: используется указатель string, передаваемый putenv(). **В частности, эта строка становится частью окружения**; последующее её изменение приводит к  изменению  окружения.  Таким образом,  **ошибочным  будет  вызывать  putenv()  с автоматической переменной** в качестве аргумента, так как после возврата из вызвавшей функции строка string является частью окружения.

Другими словами, `putenv()` пожно передавать только строки в статической (`static char []` или `const char *str="foo=bar"`) или динамической (выделенной через `malloc()`) области памяти. Причём во втором случае это чревато утечкой, например в случае удаления переменной.

Так что для переменных создаваемых в процессе исполнения программы стоит использовать [`setenv()`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=setenv&category=3&russian=0).

Answer (score 2):

Открываем [мануал](https://linux.die.net/man/3/putenv):

> The string pointed to by `string` becomes part of the environment, so altering the string changes the environment.

То есть `putenv` не копирует строку, а сохраняет указатель на нее.

Пока вам нужна эта переменная, нельзя разрушать массив, который вы передали в `putenv`.

Answer (score 1):

В виде

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void test()
{
    const char* variable = "test=privet";
    putenv(variable);
}
int main()
{
    test();
    printf ("%s\n", getenv("test"));
    return 0;
}
```

всё работает. gcc 6.3.0